# Dynamic variable selection

Tags: python, automation

I am writing automation for generic form where I m not sure of what kind of data I may get, Example I m not sure how many variables I may get...? consider I may get 13 variables ...How to accommodate this variables in my python code...? Yes I can write code for this if it is same always...? what if i get only 5 variables in the next run time. I need code for this part...that rest of the code should run based on this 5 variables or what ever the variables selected initially..either 5 or 13 the dynamic part.

Comment: You can use a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I get 3variable on a GET call

for namesake these are the variables you receive

```
result_of_get=["something","something","anotherthing"] 
dynamic_vars={}
```

now go over each items and store it in a dict

```
for var in range(len(result_of_get)):
    dynamic_vars[var]=result_of_get[var]

print(dynamic_vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
inp = input("Enter strings: ").split()

def do_something(*args):
    # if you want to operate on each element individually
    for arg in args:
        if arg == arg[::-1]:
            print(arg,'is palindrome')
        else:
            print(arg,'is not a palindrome')
    # if you want to use the entire list
    print(max(args))
do_something(*inp)
```

Output:

```
Enter strings: ada python c C++
ada is palindrome
python is not a palindrome
c is palindrome
C++ is not a palindrome
python
```

Answer (score 0):

Python enables you to accept a variable amount of arguments into any function using:

```
def foo(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

If you need the arguments to have names, pass them as keyword arguments:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        print(name, value)
```